# How to use a powershell script into c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to use a powershell script into c# code by hard coding means. I don't want user to enter the code at runtime. I'm very new to powershell. What can I do?

Comment: I am trying to fetch WindowsFeatures using Powershell and then importing the result in a windows form.I thought of using addScript and addCommand  to do this.It can be done by that but now I am struck in using 
PS C:\> Import-Module ServerManager

PS C:\> Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Installed -match “True”} | Select-Object -Property Name
but this code in powrshell is giving error,it says can't load ServerManager. I am using Window 7 and want to validate windowsfeatures in my own local machine.

Comment: Don't add additional information in comments; people can't see them there. Instead, [edit] your question and add them there instead. You'll find the [edit] link right below the tags in your question (in this case, right between `c#-4.0` and `powershell-v2.0`).

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that SeverManager Module works in Windows Server only ,so I am now using Windows Server 2012 to do so. and is working.